# Handling redirects and passing form data in NextJS 14 with DotNet Backend APIs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm currently learning and implementing NextJS 14 for my frontend code, which integrates with my DotNet Backend APIs. In my scenario, merchants call my POST API to submit formData. Upon receiving a success response from the backend, I need to redirect to a specific page and also pass the received form data to that page for rendering.

Here's the relevant code snippet for the POST request:

```
    export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
        const formData = await request.formData();
        let formDataObject: Record<string, string> = {};
        formData.forEach((value, key) => {
        formDataObject[key] = value.toString();
        });

        try {
            const res = await fetch(`${process.env.BACKEND_BASE_URL}/Transaction`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(formDataObject),
            });
            return NextResponse.redirect("http://localhost:3000/Ecommerce/Payment");
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Error while calling Post Transaction API2: ", err)
            return NextResponse.error();
        }
    }
```

I'm struggling to understand how to handle redirects in NextJS and whether I need to use a different approach to achieve my goal. Specifically, how can I redirect to my page (http://localhost:3000/Ecommerce/Payment) and pass the received form data from merchant to render on that page on backend API success?

Any guidance or code examples on handling redirects and passing data in this scenario would be greatly appreciated. Thank you! Alternatively, please guide is storing base URL in .env the correct way?

I tried this and it redirects but I am trying to not send formData as params

```
    if (res.ok) {
        // Request was successful
        console.log(`Response Body: ${res.json()}`);
        return new Response(null, {
            status: 302,
            headers: {
                "Location": "/Ecommerce/Payfast/CardInfo"
            }
        });
    } else {
        // Handle the error
        console.error(`Error: ${res.status} - ${res.statusText}`);
    }
```